# Sum rows of 2D array with elements of 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two ndarrays: 
`a = [[1, 2], [100, 200]]` and 
`b = [10, 20]`

Is it possible to get such ndarray using numpy:
`[[1 + 10, 2 + 10], [100 + 20, 200 + 20]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

```
    import numpy as np
    a = np.array([[1, 2], [100, 200]])
    b = np.array([10, 20])
    
    result = a + b.reshape(-1, 1) # is a column
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to transpose the first array, perform the addition, then transpose back:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [100, 200]])
b = np.array([10, 20])
x = a.T + b
print(x)
# [[ 11 120]
#  [ 12 220]]
print(x.T)
# [[ 11  12]
#  [120 220]]
```

Note that transposing an array is "free" so doing it several times is not a worry.

---

---

---

**Edit:** just for completeness, I have added a benchmarking test to compare all the approaches and they all seem to take the same time.

```
transposition: 0.180 ms
reshaping: 0.179 ms
newaxis: 0.181 ms
```

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter
N = 10_000_000

@contextmanager
def time_this(message=""):
    t0 = perf_counter()
    yield
    dt = perf_counter() - t0
    print(f"{message}: {dt:.3f} ms")
    
a = np.random.random((N, 2))
b = np.random.random(N,)

with time_this("transposition"):
    (a.T + b).T    
with time_this("reshaping"):
    a + b.reshape(-1, 1)
with time_this("newaxis"):
    a + b[:,None]
```

Comment: It's more memory and more computations. If `b` contains 1M elements, tranposing is better.

Comment: Adding a dimension (using `np.newaxis` or `None`) doesn't create a new array. (I don't think `reshape` does either)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Ah you are right, the `reshape` does not add time. Interesting, I was convinced otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
a + b[:,None]
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

```
b[:,None]
```

is

```
array([[10],
       [20]])
```

So by summing the two arrays, the array

```
array([[10],
       [20]])
```

will be broadcasted and summed to each column of `a`, producing the wanted result.

---

Output:

```
array([[ 11,  12],
       [120, 220]])
```

Comment: Thanks, @PranavHosangadi, for your comment. I have just added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I remember being confused by the `[:, None]` notation when I first encountered it. An answer that explains what's going on is so much more helpful!